Will there be a group policy option to disable the keyboard focusable scroller changes that are coming with Chrome v130?
From everything I have found, it looks like there will be a change coming in Chrome v130 with keyboard focusable scrollers. We have an application that a large portion of our users use daily and we know that there is a problem with the version of the software we are using and the upcoming change to the "keyboard focusable scrollers". We have worked with the vendor of the software and they are only making a change to the latest version of their software to fix this. Unfortunately we aren't on that version yet and won't be by the time Google releases this in v130 if I have read everything correctly.
The vendor's "solution" to this is to modify the flag "Enables keyboard focusable scrollers" and set it to disabled. Reading the warning on the experiments page really makes me feel that this is not a viable production solution.
My two questions are:

Will this change to Chrome be pushed to users in v130 like I have read?

Will a corresponding group policy option be available to disable this feature on our machines?


Using the flag to disable this like the vendor indicates would work, but that does not appear to be a valid option for our production environment.
